# Aliased assocation using one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Model called Location.

I'd like to have it such that a location can have many neighbors which are also Locations.

Every neighbor would be a Location.

I'd like to be able to call `Location.neighbors`.
Calling this should give me a list of locations

How would I set this up in the model and/or migration

Comment: An assocation is not the right answer here. Instead you should add coordinates (latitude and longitude) to the locations table and do a geospatial query to get other nearby locations. The [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem can be used for this.

Comment: Just saw this. Would it matter if these locations aren't listed on Google maps? I can still get the coordinates in the approximate location where they would be if google had mapped them out.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. You're just using a haversine formula to calculate the distances between the points in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `has_many` statement to your model

```rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :neighbors, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: :neighbour_id
end
```

And a little migration to add the column to your locations

```rb
def change
  add_column :locations, :neighbor_id, :bigint
end
```

Comment: This won't actually work for the requirements though as it would just create a one to many assocation when what you actually need is many to many.

Comment: @max mhh... yes you're right. So you need a Helper accosiation. I will correct my answer.

Comment: An assocation is not the answer at all here. Even if you add a join table its just going to swell exponentially with the number of locations and result in hideous queries and memory issues. This is a fairly typical "X & Y problem" - the OP has identified a problem and thinks that X (assocations) is the solution but when they actually should be asking "I have a location, how do I find nearby locations?".

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but there is no GPS functionality. I have manually added all locations and will manually have to create each neighbor/s. Also it is very similar if not identical to a situation where a user has many friends who are also users